# The resetForm method of Formik does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, reset, formik

I'm using `Formik` in my application and I want to cancel changes made to a form and revert it to its initial values (this is not about clearing form after submit, which is what most tutorials and issues are about).

Here is a simple use case:

1. user loads a form (with say 2 fields "email" and "address", and initial values:
   email: "foo@gmail.com",
   address: "bar"
2. user starts editing the email field. But then he decide to cancel the changes made and to
   revert to initial values (meaning "foo@gmail", "bar").

```
const MyForm = () => (
 <Formik initialValues={{ email:"foo@gmail.com", address: "bar" })>
   ...
 </Formik>
)
```

I use the `resetForm`. But it does not revert my form to its initial values

```
 const ResetButtom = () => {
  const { resetForm } = useFormikContext();
  return (
   <Button onClick={() => resetForm()} {...} />
     Reset
   </Button>
  )
 }
```

How can I achieve this functionality with Formik?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would approach this by keeping the original initial values as a reusable variable

```
const initialValues= { email: 'foo@email.com' }
```

```
<Formik initialValues={initialValues} ... />
```

and then:

```
<Button onClick={() => resetForm(initialValues)} {...} />
  Reset
</Button>
```

If you are using Formik v2:

```
<Button onClick={() => resetForm({ values: initialValues })} {...} />
  Reset
</Button>
```

Alternatively, you can use `setValues` in the similar manner:

```
<Button onClick={() => setValues({ ...initialValues })} {...} />
  Reset
</Button>
```

Comment: I've actually tried the above code, with no result (hence I came to look for an answer here). This is the version of formik I'm using: 2.1.5

Comment: I've added an alternative to my answer

Answer (score 0):

This modification of [Antonio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64253059) helped me to reset the initialValues.

```
const genInitialValues = () => ({
  textField: "",
  customField: [],
});

  <Formik
    initialValues={genInitialValues()}
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
      ...
      actions.resetForm({ values: genInitialValues() });
    }
  ... />
```